# Hibernate DTO query with entity

Tags: hibernate

We are migrating to Hibernate 6.2 from 5.6.

One of our queries returns a DTO with an entity (Property) inside, looks like:

```
select new be.MyDto(
    e3.name, 
    (select p from Property p where p.definition.name = 'domain' and p.concept.wuuid = e3.wuuid)
)
from Entity1 e1 join e1.entity2 e2 join e2.entity3 e3
where e1.workRelation.id = :id
```

In Hibernate 5.6 2 queries are executed:
The first selects the id of the entity for the subquery.
Next the entity with the id is fetched with a query and the DTO is instantiated with the entity.

In Hibernate 6.2 only the first query is executed and Hibernate only injects the id as Long in the DTO.

Is there any way to make Hibernate 6.2 inject the entity in the DTO?

Comment: Try to rewrite subquery with left join